# Control of SurvivalFunction probability scale

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, logarithmic-scale

Don't know how to get around this error message:Charting Common Dump Base. Isn't Mathematica supposed to figure it out automatically?

```
ccdf1 = LogLogPlot[
  SurvivalFunction[NormalDistribution[0.499603, 3.62423], x], {x, 
   0.017306, 1000}, Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
     Automatic}, {{0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 500, 1000}, Automatic}}, 
  LabelStyle -> {21, GrayLevel[0]}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"  Volume (\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Mu]m\), \(\(3\
\)\(\\\ \)\)]\))", "CCDF"}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Blue}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

Please indicate where I am going wrong.
Many thanks!
PS: I tried to enter very low probability values but still could not get to work.

Comment: No error when I run the code (v. 10.4, Mac).

Comment: @David G.Stork. I am very surprised!  Do you mind sharing your plot ? I do get a plot too but what I don't get is  a probability scale. The reason why because this emprical data of a Pareto so  the Normal is expected to be practically imposssible ( i.e very very low excedance) thus my problem with the scale. Any fix ?

Comment: This is what I get on MMA 11.1.1 Win7: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rpc3x.png. No errors either.

Comment: @MarcoB. That exactly what I need. If I run that on an Ubutntu 16.04 ay my university .Would that work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)
```

With your `xmax == 1000`, I get an error message of `General::munfl` (i.e., machine underflow) which is a new error message in version 11.3 and the y-axis ticks are not displayed.

```
ccdf1 = LogLogPlot[
  SurvivalFunction[NormalDistribution[0.499603, 3.62423], x], {x, 0.017306, 
   1000}, Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {{0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 500, 1000}, 
     Automatic}}, LabelStyle -> {21, GrayLevel[0]}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"  Volume (\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(μm\), \(\(3\)\(\\\ \
\)\)]\))", "CCDF"}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Blue}, 
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Restricting `xmax` to `135` eliminates the error message and displays the y-axis ticks.

**EDIT:** Added [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html) to plot.

```
ccdf1 = LogLogPlot[
  SurvivalFunction[NormalDistribution[0.499603, 3.62423], x], {x, 0.017306, 
   135}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {{0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100}, 
     Automatic}}, LabelStyle -> {21, GrayLevel[0]}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"  Volume (\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(μm\), \(\(3\)\(\\\ \
\)\)]\))", "CCDF"}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Blue}, 
  ImageSize -> Large,
  Epilog -> 
   Inset[LogLogPlot[
     SurvivalFunction[NormalDistribution[0.499603, 3.62423], x], {x, 0.017306,
       10}, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
     FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, 
        Automatic}, {{0.01, 0.1, 1, 10}, Automatic}}, 
     LabelStyle -> {14, GrayLevel[0]}, PlotRange -> All], {1, 0}, {-0.1, .5}, 
    7.5]]
```

[image]